# Не получается вернуть на страницу с массивом данных, код ниже как это сделать?

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно вернуться на homepage с массивом. Проблема в том что массив вернуть не получается, может дело в синтаксисе (я не то пишу). Помогите вернуть массив.

```
return redirect()->route('homepage')->with(['array' => $array]);
```

Comment: А как вы себе это представляете? Вы делаете редирект на страницу, вы не сможете передать туда массив. Нужно искать другой вариант реализации.

Comment: нашёл, можно вот так сделать:
return redirect()->route('homepage', ['array' => $array]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$data = ['key_1' => 'value_1', 'key_2' => 'value_2'];
return redirect()->route('homepage')->with(['data' => $data]);
```

Вывод в шаблоне:

```
<p>
    {{ session('data.key_1') }}
    {{ session('data.key_2') }}
</p>
```